# How to load a GluonTS DeepAR model

Tags: deep-learning, gluon, scoring

I am new to GluonTS and deep learning in general. I have a GluonTS DeepAR model which has files like -

```
myPrefix-xxxx.params
myPrefix-network.json
```

What is the way to load this model for scoring? I tried below but this looks for prefix-symbol.json

```
import mxnet as mx
model = mx.mod.Module.load(myPrefix,epochs)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to load a GluonTS model is to use the Predictor class and deserialize it -

```
from gluonts.model.predictor import Predictor
from pathlib import Path

model = Predictor.deserialize(Path(path_to_the_model))
```